# Sort hash by key in descending order

Tags: ruby, sorting, hash

I have the following hash:

```
{"2013-08-12"=> 10, "2013-08-13"=> 20, "2013-11-11"=>30, "2013-11-14"=> 40}
```

What I want to do is to sort it by key (dates in format yyyy-mm-dd) in descending order:

```
{"2013-11-14"=> 40, "2013-11-11"=>30, "2013-08-13"=> 20, "2013-08-12"=> 10}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible.

```
Hash[
  {"2013-08-12"=> 10, "2013-08-13"=> 20, "2013-11-11"=>30, "2013-11-14"=> 40}
  .sort_by{|k, _| k}.reverse
]

# => {
  "2013-11-14" => 40,
  "2013-11-11" => 30,
  "2013-08-13" => 20,
  "2013-08-12" => 10
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that it's available only in Ruby 1.9.x or higher. Previous versions don't preserve `Hash` keys sequence.

Comment: I don't think you need to note that. Ruby 1.8.7 became obsolete a long time ago. Even Ruby 1.9 is old. For me, even Ruby 2.0 is becoming old as I am using Ruby 2.1. More importantly, the question would not have made sense with Ruby 1.8.

Comment: Thank you saws, it worked like a charm. Marek, thank you for noticing this, this approach suits me as I use 1.9.3

Comment: Obsolete - yes. no longer used - sadly no. Particularly in larger organisations and legacy projects 1.8.x is alive and kicking, unfortunately.